# Okta SSO across multiple apps

Tags: reactjs, okta, okta-signin-widget

I'm using Okta to manage the users of my application, which is made in React.
I implemented a custom login page with is working fine and authenticating the user. One of the requisites of the App is that when a user is already authenticated in the Okta domain (ex. account.mycompany.com) the user must not have to authenticate in this app again. It should keep the authentication. I'm using [this Okta package](https://github.com/okta/okta-react) in my project

I managed to do that and when the user is already authenticated in the Okta domain the app loads his authentication and continues the flow. The problem is that when the user is not authenticated it's sending the user to the okta hosted login page. I need it to send to mine.

Below is the code of my app. In the comment the line where this is done which is where I would like to know what to change to have the expected behavior.

```
const MyApp = () => {
  const defaultTheme = useTheme();
  const theme = createTheme(deepmerge(defaultTheme, MainTheme));
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(getOktaConfig());

  const triggerLogin = async () => {
    // this is the line that handles the user already authenticated 
    // and also the line that is sending the user to the okta hosted login page.
    // What do I change so it continues to authenticate the user when he's already 
    // authenticated in the domain but also it doesn't send him to the okta hosted login page?
    await oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
  };

  const onAuthRequired = async () => {
    const previousAuthState = oktaAuth.authStateManager.getPreviousAuthState();
    if (!previousAuthState || !previousAuthState.isAuthenticated) {
      // App initialization stage
      await triggerLogin();
    } else {
      // Ask the user to trigger the login process during token autoRenew process
      navigate(routes.SIGN_IN().PATH, { replace: true });
    }
  };

  const restoreOriginalUri = async () => {
    navigate(routes.DASHBOARD().PATH, { replace: true });
  };

  return (
    <Security
      oktaAuth={oktaAuth}
      onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired}
      restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppProviders>
          <LayoutWrapper>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <Router />
            </ThemeProvider>
          </LayoutWrapper>
        </AppProviders>
      </Provider>
    </Security>
  );
};
```

Thanks for any help

I have already tried to pass the original uri in the `signInWithRedirect` method.

`await oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect( { originalUri:routes.SIGN_IN().PATH });`

And it didnt give me the behavior I need. I feel like I need a way to inform Okta, via code or a configuration, the url of the login page to redirect the user to when he's not authenticated. Not sure if it's possible though.

Comment: there are only 2 ways to sign a user into an OIDC app: either you redirect them to Okta login page (like you do) or to have an okta sign-in widget embedded into your app so that it does authentication w/o a redirect. I suggest you to research the latter approach. Other options are also possible but they are bit tricky to implement

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev This is what is confusing to me. If I do the authentication without the redirect I won't load previous authentication in the domain. If I make it load the previous authentication in the domain, it works but redirects the user to the custom okta page when he's not authenticated. I can't find a way to make both work

Comment: for authN w/o redirect to work properly apps and okta have to be on the same top level domain to be able to share cookies. But again I think your use case is bit complicated to address with a short answer. Try to check devforum.okta.com for similar use cases, where it was described. I remember some threads with a similar requirements

Answer (score 0):

Third-party cookies are important. I was testing in incognito and chrome comes with this option selected by default “Block third-party cookies in Incognito”, which was preventing the flow to work properly.

Since I’ve seen this same question on many places on the internet I’m pasting below the piece of code that made it work in my React App.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (oktaAuth.authStateManager.getAuthState()?.isAuthenticated) {
      navigate(routes.DASHBOARD().PATH, { replace: true });
    } else {
      oktaAuth.session.exists().then((exists) => {
        if (exists) {
          oktaAuth.token
            .getWithoutPrompt({
              responseType: ['token', 'id_token'],
            })
            .then((res) => {
              oktaAuth.handleLoginRedirect(res.tokens);
            });
        }
      });
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Thanks